# Stream Jackbox games with friends in voice chat

Tags: jackbox-party-pack

I am looking for a way to share my game audio in a voice chat environment.

Goal: Have a group of friends playing JackBox games remotely. Then stream said game to twitch.
Problem: My friends can see the game video via screensharing but cannot hear the audio except to watch the stream, but that means that they hear themselves repeated.

Possible Solutions:
I've tried installing VB Cable and VoiceMeeter to try and push my system audio to the voice chat. I followed this tutorial.

Even after following it exactly, I could not make the game sound go through to my voice chat. I'm ok not having a mic via my computer because I can join the call through another device. I don't think I got it set up correctly at all though. It wasn't behaving like the tutorial at all.
I tried using stereo mix recording device to no avail.

Any other ideas for streaming JackBox games with the players in a voice call together?

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing on a console, you can do a group chat or party. By doing this you'll be able to hear each other and stream the game too. Streaming on Mixer for Xbox will have a much smaller delay.

Comment: I do like mixer :) I am currently using a capture card to play the game on Xbox but stream from my computer. So the issue l have with having the group chat get the game audio from the stream is they have to hear themselves. So the end goal is to have the group chat be heard by the stream as well. But maybe i can stream to a different mixer account from the Xbox that the players can watch and then stream the group chat and the game from my pc. Can you tell I’m desperate :)